# Как запустить все .lnk-файлы из папки одновременно?

Tags: bat

Есть много файлов .lnk (ярлыков) в папке, из нее я запускаю батник, который должен запустить все эти файлы одновременно. Как сделать?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
%~d0
for /r c:\ %%i in (*.lnk) do start /wait "" "%%i"
pause
```

не помогло, ярлыки запускались поочередно. (пока не закроешь один, другой не открывался)

Comment: Похоже на шутку, провокацию, пользы - нуль

Answer (score 4):

Для запуска без ожидания - не нужно использовать флаг `/wait`

**Не советую пробовать вышеприведенный код бездумно - он будет вызывать все линки с диска С: рекурсивно со всех подкаталогов!**

Шутник, однако.

Comment: Но это хоть просто баловство, это те не пони ;)

Comment: путь конечно был другой :)

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
%~d0
for /r c:\mikrotiks\ %%i in (*.lnk) do  "%%i"
pause

тоже не работает. тоже возникает ожидание закрытия первого открытого

Comment: Ну я уже же написал, убирай `/wait` - и очередной вызов не будет ждать завершения текущего вызываемого процесса, а сразу "прыгнет" вызывать следующий очередной.